# How to display Chinese Chracter on JBoss 4.2.3GA

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

Same as the title, Kindly advice how to configure JBoss to display chinese character.

The unreadable character is making trouble for me when i saw the unreadable words and have no idea what is going on with the error occurred. Kindly advice.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to open that file specifying in your editor the proper encoding

Comment: is that mean JBoss is not support chinese character on the console?
so alternative solution is i write a system to specific encode my unreadable chinese character from JBoss console file?

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly assumed you were opening an XML file manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Edit JBOSS_HOME//server/(default)/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/server.xml and edit the following line (I guess UTF-8 should be Ok, but I think you'll have to try with other values as well):

```
<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

Edit eithr JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.bat or JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh depending on the OS you're using. Set the -Dfile.encoding option accordingly (again, try first UTF-8):

```
JAVA_OPTS=JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```